# React to rerender immediately

Tags: reactjs

I have a single React component that looks something like this:

```
var SendFormToServer = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        Values: React.PropTypes.object,
        getValues: React.PropTypes.func,
        sendToServer: React.PropTypes.func
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            Values: this.props.Values
        };
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        var scope = this.props.getValues();

        this.setState({ Values: scope });
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.props.sendToServer(e);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="pull-right">
                <div id="model" style={{"display": "none"}}>
                    company = '{this.state.Values.Company}'{newLine}
                    user = '{this.state.Values.User}'{newLine}
                    notes = '{this.state.Values.Notes}'{newLine}
                </div>
                <input type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleClick} value="Submit" />
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

The problem is.. is that the re-rendering occurs AFTER the handleClick() is finished. It doesn't occur after this.setState as many people mentioned on stackoverflow, and it doesn't even occur after this.forceUpdate().

I need the rerendering to occur before this.props.sendToServer function gets called. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to come up with a different solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState()` and `this.forceUpdate()` are asynchronous functions so they don't update immediately. However what you can do is pass your next function as a callback to `setState` like this:

```
this.setState({ Values: scope }, () => {
    this.props.sendToServer(e);
});
```

Comment: WOW! I never seen this trick before!! this is amazing.. thanks!

Comment: @sksallaj Would you mind marking one of the answers correct either mine or the other if it has solved your problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to, but stackoverflow gives a limit to how quickly you can mark an answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution here involves realizing, first of all, that `this.setState` will cause an update already. If you want to make that second call synchronously, you'd put it in the callback:

```
this.setState({ Values: scope }, () =>  this.props.sendToServer(e));
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: and just fyi, your component DOES get re-rendered before your call as it stands, it's just that it's asynchronous and the double rendering takes time, leading to racing conditions

Comment: AHH thanks! Its crazy how both you and winhowes answered at the same time.. I never seen that trick before. thank you!

Comment: haha not a trick, just a slightly hidden feature often overlooked